# Выборка с MySQL с двух идентификаторов

Tags: php

Как сформулировать такой запрос

```
$yap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvp WHERE protivnik_1='".$_SESSION['username']."' или protivnik_2='".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
```

Comment: @oOKomarOo, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуй)

```
$yap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvp WHERE protivnik_1='".$_SESSION['username']."' || protivnik_2='".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
```

Comment: в SQL обычно пишут **OR**